# Allow users to add elements to a list but do not allow them to view it - client side

Tags: javascript, permissions

I have a form which users fill in, and the information is inserted into a Sharepoint List using Javascript.

I don't want to allow the users to view the list, but add elements to it using Javascript.

**I searched the Internet and found some answers here on Stackoverflow which advise to use `elevated privileges` for that section of code, but I cannot use Visual Studio - I have to do everything client-side.**

Any other solutions that **do not involve Visual Studio**?

Thank you

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: Is it an InfoPath form?

Comment: By the way, this is not possible with purely client side code.  The Add Items permission is dependent on the List Items permission, so you cannot secure truly secure the list, since a user can simply disable javascript in their browser, and CSOM doesn't provide any methods to add as another user.

Comment: SharePoint 2013, no InfoPath, just a HTML form with Javascript to insert the items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an Add Only permission level, but by it will include view items. If you apply this to the list permissions, it would allow them to add items. You could use the item level permission settings (List Settings -> Advanced settings -> Item-level Permissions set Read access: to Read items that were created by the user) that allows them to view only the items they've submitted not the entire list content.

It doesn't quite fit what you are trying to do, but it is close. With some UI obfuscation, you could get there.

Comment: You could use the item level permission settings that allows them to view only the items they've submitted not the entire list content. - How can I do that more specifically? Can you add some details please? Thank you

Comment: It would be perfect for the users to see ONLY the items THEY've added

Comment: updated with how to get to the item level permission setting

Comment: Thank you so much, I will mark this as accepted as soon as StackOverflow will let me (it says I must wait 22 more seconds)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make two lists, and utilize a Workflow.  The concept is user has add/list permissions on `List1`, no permissions on `List2`.  User creates item in `List1`, Workflow then moves the list item to `List2`.  You can either leave the item in `List1` if you wish the users to be able to see the items they've added (though another workflow may be needed to sync changes), or you can delete the item.  This will require that workflows can use app permissions site feature is enabled and you will have to use app steps in the workflow.  You can read about how to turn this feature on, and how to create an app step [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column to your list with the account username, and then use a VIEW, that only show items for the current user filtered.

i.e. 
add the Column "user" (user or group type, choose only person), and in your list choose the user using the people picker.

The public and default view must filter "when the field user is equal to [me]"